# PHP downloading instead of running

Tags: php, forms

I am working on visual studio code making a few web pages and I need to send html form data from one to another. I am using the get method but when I submit the form the PHP file downloads instead of running, is there a way to fix this?

```
        <form action="login.php" method="get">
            <p class="normal" id="samelinechild">Dora the</p>
            <input name="verification" id="very"  type="text">
            <p class="normal"id="samelinechild">explorer</p>
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
```

Comment: Are you running this on an apache server?

Comment: This problem arises mostly when you are not running your code on server

Comment: So do I need a server if so which one?

Answer (score -1):

If you send data use POST method not GET. I don't know if this will fix the problem but it's the rule.